# MessageBox loses focus in maximized MDI form

Tags: .net-2.0, mdi, messagebox

I have an MDI application (written in .NET 2.0) which lets users open multiple child forms.  The child forms are always maximized inside the MDI parent.  When the MDI parent is maximized and I attempt to do a MessageBox.Show, the MessageBox doesn't show.  If I do an alt-tab (or even just press alt) the MessageBox pops to the front.

Any ideas how to make that sucker show up to begin with?

This is only a problem when the MDI parent is maximized...

Comment: Tad! Friendfeed! Wish I had something intelligent to say on MDI question.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you ever discover a solution to this problem? Does anyone have any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Try using
[MessageBox.Show(Window owner, string message, string caption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598681.aspx)
Setting the MDI application as owner so the MB is shown in the front

Ah, you should also add some tags to your post.