# MessageBox doesn't show on mdi form after a long calculation

Tags: c#, mdi, messagebox

This is a very similar problem to [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97344/messagebox-loses-focus-in-maximized-mdi-form), sadly that one was never answered either.

I have a MDI Main forum that hosts several children forms. One of them does a long calculation and throws an exception if an error occurs (all work is done on the same thread). I then try to inform the user of an error with an messagebox, however it doesn't appear (but steals focus from the MDI Main, so the application is completely unresponsive).

The beheviour changes slightly if I call Application.DoEvents() (evil I know, but this is a last resort thing). Then the forms remain completely active and the messagebox only appears after I change active application (Alt+Tab) to something else and then back again.

What can I do to make sure the messagebox will be visible? I have already tried passing both, active child and MDI Main as parameter to the MessageBox.Show method. It doesn't change the behaviour.

**To clarify:** the messagebox is a part of the child form, however at this point I am willing to show it in any way that doesn't *break* the application. The messagebox should be modal, but it should be visible so it can be acknowledged by the user.

Comment: Are you still having problems with this?

Comment: I have wrote a work-around that uses another thread to show the messagebox. I still don't think this question is answered though and my solution is a workaround so I don't think I will use it to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. When pressed ALT the popup showed.

It turned out to be a LinkedLabel that had the AutoSize property to true. The LinkedLabel was inside a FlowLayoutPanel. When I set the LinkedLabel.Text property to String.Empty. The LinkedLabel constantly tried to resize, which was causing the GUI to be constantly busy.

When I turned off the AutoSize property and the GUI no longer had to recalculate the positions. The GUI was no free. And the popup showed.

There could be other controls that are behaving the same.
See also:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/116884

Answer (score 0):

Is the MessageBox shown in the MainForm or as part of the ChildForms? If the MessageBox is in the child Forms maybe you could pass an event back to the MainForm and open the MessageBox there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that messageboxes tend to be modal.
In this instance I think that you'd do far better to use a delegate or an event with a handler in your main MDI code. That way your main application displays the message boxes. You can easily redefined an EventArgsType if you wish to pass whatever information that you require.